# Is the language $L$ of coded CFG's Turing decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, context-free, reductions, computation-models

Consider the following language

$L$ = {$<G><w>$ | $G$ is a CFG and $w\in L(G)$}

Now, I wish to prove that $L$ is Turing decidable. My gut tells me to construct a Turing machine that simulates a NPDA that decide whether $w$ is indeed in $L(G)$. The TM will hold two tapes: one for the input and another to simulate the stack.

Am I in the right direction here?

Comment: There are many algorithms that decide whether $w \in L(G)$ for context-free $G$. See for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Parsing).